# kivy run function on background

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy

I am creating my first app for mobile phones with python and kivy. Its main function is a **countdown timer**, that I would like to keep counting **even when the phone is off**. I have looked into this a little bit, but I am still not sure what the correct way to go about this is. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say "off", do you mean literally powered off or simply not in use? If the former, you probably need to use pyjnius to call the android api for scheduling tasks. If the latter, you could still do that, or you could use a Service to keep some Python code running while the app isn't in use.

Comment: No, I mean just switched off or using another app, not completely powered off. I will try pyjnius and let you know how it went!

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to make note of the actual time your countdown starts from (e.g. 3:46 pm march 20, 2020). This way, your app can just display the time remaining in your countdown by calculating the time now minus the start time. This goes around the issue of apps not being able to do anything while they aren't open (on iOS, at least)